# How to execute sparql query in jsp for rdf?

Tags: jsp, jstl, sparql, ontology

This is my code of jsp in which, I have insert the sparql query to retrieve information out of it but it give errors in code. Please tell me possible solution to solve this problem.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.semanticweb.org/shahrukh/ontologies/2017/4/" 
prefix="sparql" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <sparql:sparql>
 <html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Research Papers of 2017</h1>

<!-- <sparql:select var="modules">  -->

<!-- retrieve data of research paper -->
<sparql:select var="mod" model="tb">
    SELECT ?title ?publisher
    WHERE { 
            ?m rdf:title ?title .
            ?m rdf:publisher ?publisher . 
    }


</sparql:select>
</body>
</html>
</sparql:sparql>
```

Comment: Java server pages are a mechanism to run Java code inside a web page, or not? Which Java API do you use to execute the SPARQL query?

Comment: We are using Jena API.

Comment: That's for sure a necessary information. And what is the exception? Without nobody can help you.

Comment: By the way, your SPARQL query is 1) missing the prefix declarations 2) it'S poor practice to reuse the `rdf` prefix for your custom data, i.e. `rdf:title` and `rdf:publisher` should belong to your own namespace.

Comment: I am new in Semantic web. So, I have no knowledge of its basic syntax.

Comment: Nobody can help without seeing the error message + the Java code. But as I said, you have to add the prefix declarations to the SPARQL query. At least that's something that will also lead to parsing errors in Jena.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/RDFNode.

Comment: You have to add the Jena JAR files to the Java classpath. By the way, don't use such an old Jena version. Latest Jena is 3.4.0, your is something from 2.x